# Deleting a value from a list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have defined a recursive function `delete()` that takes in two parameters:

- lst : of type `list`
- to_delete : a value that needs to be removed from the list

However, I have used the function `del()`, one that we haven't learned yet. So I am wondering whether there is a simpler way to output the same solution without the use of the function `del()`

This is my code:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
                 to_delete : represents a value one wants to delete from the list
    returns : another list with the same elements minus the ones one asks to delete
    """
    if not lst:
        return []
    else:
        if lst[0] == to_delete:
            del lst[0]
            return delete(lst[1:], to_delete)
        return [lst[0]] + delete(lst[1:], to_delete)

print(delete([1,2,3,4,5,5,6,5,7,5], 5))
```

Output:

```
> [1,2,3,4,6]       #where is 7 ?
```

Comment: Is recursion mandatory?

Comment: of utter importance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 7 is missing, because you return `delete(lst[1:], to_delete)` even when you just `del`eted `lst[0]`: You should use `delete(lst[0:], to_delete)` here.
- The alternative is *not* to `del` the 0th element and *just* return `delete(lst[1:], to_delete)`.
- Instead of doing this recursively, you can also just use a list comprehension:

.

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    return [element for element in lst if element != to_delete]
```

Comment: The only answer here that respects OP's use of recursion and explained why it failed :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Recursion

Even with recursion, you don't need to use `del`:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
                to_delete : represents a value one wants to delete from the list
    returns : another list with the same elements minus the ones one asks to delete
    """
    if not lst:
        return []
    if lst[0] == to_delete:
        return delete(lst[1:], to_delete)
    return [lst[0]] + delete(lst[1:], to_delete)
```

As you can see, you are repeating yourself a bit (`delete(lst[1:], to_delete)` is used twice), so you can shorten this to:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
                to_delete : represents a value one wants to delete from the list
    returns : another list with the same elements minus the ones one asks to delete
    """
    if not lst:
        return []
    start = [] if lst[0] == to_delete else [lst[0]]
    return start + delete(lst[1:], to_delete)
```

I don't know about its performance though.

#### No Recursion

If you don't need to use recursion, you can use list comprehensions for much less code:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    return [x for x in lst if x != to_delete]
```

In case you don't know list comprehensions well, this is logically equivalent to the following:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    res = []
    for x in lst:
        if x != to_delete:
            res.append(x)
    return res
```

**EDIT:** I missed it, but the reason you don't see `7` in the output is, that `del lst[0]` already removes the first value from the list and so, you are missing the "new" first value of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to **recreate** your list without the unwanted items:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    return [x for x in lst if x!=to_delete]

print(delete([1,2,3,4,5,5,6,5,7,5], 5))
# [1,2,3,4,6,7]
```

---

Correcting your code (but leaving recursion out of it) would look like this:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
                 to_delete : represents a value one wants to delete from the list
    returns : another list with the same elements minus the ones one asks to delete
    """
    if not lst:
        return []
    else:
        res = []
        for item in lst:
            if item == to_delete:
                continue
            else:
                res.append(item)
        return res
```

which has the same result.

---

Finally, the **recursive** option which I highly discourage for this application is the following:

```
def delete(lst, to_delete, res=[]):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
                 to_delete : represents a value one wants to delete from the list
    returns : another list with the same elements minus the ones one asks to delete
    """
    if not lst:
        return res
    else:
        item = lst[0]
        if item != to_delete:
            res.append(item)
        return delete(lst[1:], to_delete, res=res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be interested in recursion. Recursion is a functional heritage and so I will give you a glimpse of a functional perspective on the problem. Below, `delete` is a specialization of `filter`, which is a specialization of `reduce`, a simple recursive form -

```
def reduce (f, state = None, xs = [], i = 0):
  if i >= len (xs):
    return state
  else:
    return reduce \
      ( f
      , f (state, xs[i], i)
      , xs
      , i + 1
      )

def filter (f, xs = []):
  return reduce \
    ( lambda acc, x, i:
        acc + [x] if f (x) else acc
    , []
    , xs
    )

def delete (q, xs = []):
  return filter \
    ( lambda x: q != x
    , xs
    )

print (delete (5, [ 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1 ]))
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1]

print (delete ('x', 'abxcdxefxghxi'))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Functional style is not the idiomatic style of Python. Those wishing to explore functional style in Python are not completely ignored however. You can find `reduce` and `filter` (among many other useful functions) tucked away in Python's [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) module.

The definitions of `reduce` and `filter` here are my own. If you use `functools`, you'll want to read up on specific behaviors more closely.